# understanding AngularFire 3-way binding

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I can't seem to get anything working. How would I update my name?

The firebase.

```
- users
  - my_8_username
    - name "Some String"
```

The controller.

```
controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $firebase) {
  var id = $rootScope.userId
  $scope.name = $firebase(new Firebase(URL + 'users/' + id + '/name'))
  $scope.name.$bind($scope, 'name')
})
```

The markup.

```
<input ng-model="name" type="text">
```

Comment: Not enough here to help you. You haven't included the error or problem you run into, version info, nor does the code you've provided cause any problems if I make some assumptions and try it out.

Comment: @Kato does it work for you? I opened two browsers, changed the text in one, and it didn't change in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a ref to the AngularFire bindings, and then bound a scope variable to the same object. Try this instead:

```
controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $firebase) {
  var id = $rootScope.userId;
  var ref = new Firebase(URL + 'users/' + id + '/name');
  $firebase(ref).$bind($scope, 'name');
});
```

Comment: that makes more sense. It still doesn't save when I change the value tho!